# Notepad++, Location Navigate plugin: edited lines not re-marked if previously marked as saved

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ as my code editor of choice. In my Visual Studio days, I really found useful the line marking feature, where lines that had any unsaved edits would be marked red. When saved, the marking would turn green to indicate that the edits are written to the document. If those "green" lines were re-edited, they would be re-marked red until saved again and so on. In the end of the session (tab / app killed), all the markings are cleared.

Notepad++ has the "Location Navigate" plugin which has a bit wider purpose really, but I mostly use it for the line marking capability as described. While it does work much like the feature in VS, I have found that if a line is marked as "saved" (a.k.a "green"), it won't ever turn back to "edited" ("red") while in the same session, even when it is indeed heavily edited. An inadequate work-around is to "File --> Reload from Disk", but that clears all line markings (basically starts a new session of the doc).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is your question? Are you requesting an enhancement to the editor or its plugin? If yes then you may be better served on the editor or the plugin's web pages.

Comment: My question is whether edits not being marked as described is due to a settting / configuration that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly: you want a line already marked green (changed and saved), change color when you change it again.

I do not think it's possible, but you can use *'Mark Color'* and *'Save Color'* near *'Clear All'* button at the botom of the *'Location History'* pane.

It allows you to click on this field and select any color that you want to use here.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for the input! You understood my question very well, that is exactly the functionality I would like. Too bad the plugin does not seem to support it.

Comment: I realize that the plugin generally serves a different purpose. Anyway, code editors with version control integration (such as IntelliJ) handle this issue well.